# NullPointerException while trying to delete in JIRA using groovy script runner

Tags: java, groovy, nullpointerexception, jira

I am very new to groovy script runner and I have been trying to delete a field in JIRA but I always get NullPointerException.

I do understand what NullPointerMeans and I have read multiple posts online and on atlassian but nothing has helped.

Any idea / help is appreciated on how I can achieve this

```
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager
import com.atlassian.jira.ComponentManager
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.CustomField
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;

CustomFieldManager customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager();

CustomField customField_toDelete = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("12345")

customFieldManager.removeCustomField(customField_toDelete);
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.atlassian.jira.issue.managers.DefaultCustomFieldManager.removeCustomField(DefaultCustomFieldManager.java:490)
    at com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager$removeCustomField$7.call(Unknown Source)
    at Script2441.run(Script2441.groovy:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [JIRA documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/7.2.0/com/atlassian/jira/issue/CustomFieldManager.html#getCustomFieldObject-java.lang.Long-)

```
customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("12345")
```

Will return **null** if there is no customer field in JIRA with the identifier "12345", hence why

```
customFieldManager.removeCustomField(customField_toDelete)
```

Throws a null pointer (because customField_toDelete is **null**)

If the method removeCustomField was @Nullable (i.e was annotated with the Nullable annotation) then it would be ok to pass a null to the method, but since it is not annotated with the method, it throws an exception.